# Pass every command executed in the bash shell to a variable

Tags: bash

I'd like to pass every command executed in the bash shell to a variable, in order to be used to change a label showing running app.

Since newer versions of `bash` have preexec hook, `PS0` (expanded and displayed after reading a command and before the command is executed) and `PROMPT_COMMAND` (value is interpreted as a command to execute before the printing of each primary prompt), I'm thinking of using these to achieve the change of label.
`PS0` as shown below and `PROMPT_COMMAND="printf '\033kBASH\033\\'"` so that label is restored to `BASH` after the typed command is executed.

So for example, `top` is started,

`$ top`  <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Ideally `top`, as a string, would be assigned to `$TO_BE_EXECUTED_APP` var which would be used to something like
`PS0="print '\033k$TO_BE_EXECUTED_APP\033\\'"`

These escape sequences can be used by `tmux` for example to change its window label.

What I can't achieve is to populate the `$TO_BE_EXECUTED_APP` with the to-be-executed command as a string.

I tried using `$BASH_COMMAND`, no positive result.

Using this shell function I can *manually* achieve what a I need:

```
exelabel() {
        printf "\033k$@\033\\"
        "$@"
```

`$ exelabel top`  <kbd>Enter</kbd>

But of course I'd like this to be done automatically. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to get current command :

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT= history 1 | sed -e "s/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//"
```

This is what I use to display current command on xterm title :

```
PS0='$(printf "\e]0;%s\7" "$(HISTTIMEFORMAT= history 1 | sed -e "s/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//")")'
```

In your case, you can do (update after comments):

```
PS0='$(printf "\033k%s\033" "$(HISTTIMEFORMAT= history 1 | sed -e "s/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//")")'
```

or

```
PS0='$(printf "\033k%s\033\\\\" "$(HISTTIMEFORMAT= history 1 | sed -e "s/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//")")'
```

Comment: Interesting perspective, getting command from history. But I can't get it working, I'm a bit confused: `HISTTIMEFORMAT` is a known bash variable. Mine is set as `%F %T`. Also you leave a space after `=` which essentially clears `$HISTTIMEFORMAT` var, is that what you want? If I assign `'$(printf "\e]0;%s\7" "$(HISTTIMEFORMAT= history 1 | sed -e "s/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//")")'` to an arbitrary variable ie T, and then execute $T, I get `-bash: $(printf: command not found`.

Comment: Yes, `HISTTIMEFORMAT= history 1` limits the effect of `HISTTIMEFORMAT=` to `history 1`. It won't affect your HISTTIMEFORMAT setting. I updated my answer.

Comment: I posted as an answer, it wouldn't be possible to post it as a comment, check it if you like. @Philippe

Answer (score 0):

@Philippe:

Entering

```
PS0='$(printf "\033k%s\033\\" "$(HISTTIMEFORMAT= history 1 | sed -e "s/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//")")'
```

produces these errors after each <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
bash: command substitution: line 32: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
bash: command substitution: line 33: syntax error: unexpected end of file
bash: command substitution: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
bash: command substitution: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I also assigned the same line to a test variable:

```
testing='$(printf "\033k%s\033\\" "$(HISTTIMEFORMAT= history 1 | sed -e "s/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//")")'
```

If I type at prompt:
`$ $testing` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

I get this error:

```
bash: $(printf: command not found
```

Also tried to remove space after printf, the error changes to:

```
bash: $(printf"\033k%s\033\\": command not found
```

Comment: After second 033, can you try removing the 2 backskashes, or put 4 like `\\\\\` ? Your way to assign to a variable won't work. I have not found a way either.

Comment: It works! Either removing 2 \\ or 4 backslashes in total! Can you update your answer, so that I can accept it. I tried to edit it, but I got an error, edit queue is full. It may help others too. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I updated your answer and accepted it.